# Compare bash variable

Tags: bash

I need help with how to compare bash variable to a specific format.

i will read user input with read command

```
for example:
MyComputer:~/Home$ read interface
eth1
MyComputer:~/Home$ echo $interface
eth1
```

Now i need to check if "$interface" variable with IF loop(it should have "eth" in beginning and should contains numbers 0-9):

```
if [[ $interface=^eth[0-9] ]]
then
    echo "It looks like an interface name"
fi
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
if [[ $interface =~ ^eth[0-9]+$ ]]
then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: I can understand ^ in `if [[ $interface =~ ^eth[0-9]+$ ]]` however could you please explain use of ~ and +$ in bash

Comment: This is regex. The `=~` is the matching operator and `+` says that the stuff in the former `[]` should appear 1 or more times. I think the `[[ ]]` style isn't portable so one should avoid this?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash's globs for this:

```
if [[ $interface = eth+([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
    echo "It looks like an interface name"
fi
```

(avoiding regexps removes one problem). Oh, and mind the spaces around the `=` sign, and also before and after `[[` and `]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash V3+ operator `=~` as Andrew Logvinov said :

```
[[ $interface =~ ^eth[0-9]+$ ]] && # ...
```

Or :

```
if [[ $interface =~ ^eth[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    # ...
fi
```

Otherwise, you could use too `egrep` or `grep -E` (which is useful with older shells like sh...) :

```
echo "$interface"|egrep "^eth[0-9]+$" > /dev/null && # ...
```

Or :

```
if echo "$interface"|egrep "^eth[0-9]+$" > /dev/null; then
    # ...
fi
```